# Are "How do I store x" type questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are a few questions cropping up about "how do I store x" or "how long can I keep x before it goes off" and whilst I think food preservation is interesting, I tend to think that these are off topic as they aren't really about cooking.

Having said that, they are definitely about food so maybe they could be considered on topic.

I'd like to see these types of topics closed but I'm interested in others thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should our FAQ contain?](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain)

Answer (score 7):

It is of great value to average cooks and chefs and has clear objective answers. Why would it be off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

This has already received [several votes in the FAQ discussion](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain/125#125) and there were also a few food storage questions that were part of the Area 51 definition phase.  It's definitely on topic.

The site is "Food and Cooking" - not just "Cooking."  Food storage questions are still about food, and they're well within the scope of knowledge of most professionals and home cooks alike.

Answer (score 1):

I was rather strongly against these early on, partially due to its tangential nature, and greatly due to fear over [stuff like this](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/does-this-will-kill-you-count-as-a-flag-reason) - most of us, and most users we'll likely ever see here, aren't nutritionists, biologists, disease control specialists, physicians...

But I think Aaronaught made a good argument in the FAQ question: this is knowledge that *is* needed by most cooks. Allowing it means bad answers show up next to good ones and get down-voted (hopefully...) rather than as anecdotes in otherwise-unrelated questions (where they get missed by those who know better and end up doing real damage...)

Finally, common sense should tell you that if you get sick from someone you read on the 'Net, it's your own fault for blindly believing something you read on the 'Net without verifying it first.

Now, back to my frosty aged chicken-blood milkshake - tasty stuff, you should try it!

Answer (score 1):

Most of these questions are answerable by visiting stilltasty.com and searching for your food. I think it will become tiring to paste that URL over and over.

I will probably vote down any question that I can answer via that link. Perhaps people will learn eventually.

There are some exceptions that are interesting, like raw food in marinade, or other special circumstances.

Comment: I had never heard of that site until now.  Good find, but I wouldn't downvote people just for not knowing about it.

Comment: I agree with Aaronaught. Many people have not heard of stilltasty.com - and at the very least it's nice to have real people's support for what that site says. I like seeing that many others have followed the advice on stilltasty and had it work for them.