# Posts being edited that do not substantially improve and necro a post?

Tags: discussion, editing, moderation

I have noticed lately that there have been a number of old, low vote number (<1) posts re-appearing at the top of the forum. This is also happening to some recent highly voted posts. It would seem that the reason for the rise in the post visibility is that minor edits have been made to posts, usually to the question, not the answers.

Now I can see that editing to improve spelling and/or grammar and readability is a good thing and not to be discouraged, especially for posts that are likely to be seen by the wider community and potentially attract new users. However, it feels like some of these edits are made, not in the interest of making the posts better, but more for reputation farming.

So, the question is: should we be approving such edits, when they do not substantially improve the style of the post nor do they change the content of the post in any discernible way?

Edited to add: here's one [Cheeses with artificial ingredients?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/6479/revisions), I approved the edit a couple of hours ago, not realizing that it was a post from 2010. Another here: [What does simmer mean?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/19160/revisions), and here: [Pizza stone soap?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/100210/revisions) I realize that the last is a recent question, but the edits were very minor spelling fixes.

Comment: Can you link to some examples? People's notions of what's minor tend to vary a bit, so it's difficult to discuss without some specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression that any and all edits for spelling, format, and style are accepted and encouraged (with the exception of swapping between acceptable UK-US variants). You're likely seeing some combination of people hunting for their editing badges or just being a little particular.

related: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/618/17063

Comment: The post you link to explicitly mentions some edits for spelling which are not accepted or encouraged.

Comment: Can you point it out for me? I'm running low on coffee, but I don't see it. @PeterTaylor edit: oh you mean to change UK to US english. Got it. I'll edit my answer. Thanks